# Why can't I download apps on my iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I just got an iPhone 6s and I'm having trouble downloading apps. It keeps asking me to set up three security questions and when I do it says that it's downloading but then it asks me to set up security questions again, and if I say cancel then it stops downloading the app. I just keep going in circles which is quiet annoying. What can I do about this?

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244699/cant-download-any-app-from-appstore

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this **may** be an issue with your AppleID. You do have an AppleID already? If not create one, you don't have to use an iCloud.com email address you can use whatever you currently use as your AppleID.

I would log into iCloud.com and check your account settings, security and most importantly, the security questions. Maybe even change your password. Once that is done, sign out of iCloud on your iPhone and sign back in with your new credentials.

Once you have signed in again, try downloading an app. It will likely ask you for a password but should not prompt for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem, but I believe my iCloud isn’t letting me download free apps such as Spotify and other apps, due to the fact that a charge hasn’t went through to my card. Im not exactly understanding why I am not able to download an app that is free although.. I could understand if it was a purchaseable app, but I am very much irritated and confused at the moment.

Comment: Interesting. Basically, you're saying that if you don't have a recent charge, it might be hanging up and you'd need to either get a paid transaction and/or contact Apple support and there is a specific reason why this isn't working?